# Using zonal statistics in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, zonal-statistics

I have a set of temporal images of a given State with 23 districts.

When I used ArcGIS for Desktop to generate zonal statistics using the vector file of the State, the pixel counts were tabulated for these 23 districts for different periods.

I am confused to note that the pixel counts were varying between different times.

Can anybody solve my problem?

I can do it in QGIS also if the method is suggested.

Comment: What file format are the temporal images?  How were the data captured? How different are the pixel counts? Depending on format, I'm not surprised that pixel counts may be different.

Comment: Basically the file format is TIFF and the sensor is MODIS-Terra.  My interest is to study crop stress in a given area over period of time, for instance from 2000 to 2014. I like to calculate the percentage of pixels in various stress classes. However, I found the pixels counts were varying causing a worry.

Comment: If you have access to ArcGIS 10.1, you can use the tool [Tabulate Intersection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000044000000). If not (which seems to be the case), the pixel count is a good way to go. **Could it be that the data from different times have different resolution?**